# Markup code inside Custom Server Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-3.5, custom-server-controls

I'm new to custom server controls and I'm hoping to use them to build various 'modules' for different sites I build to cut down on duplicate code.

I'm familiar with custom user controls in which I can create an .ascx & .ascx.vb file which can then be imported into an .aspx page and used freely.

However, with custom server controls I cannot find a way of using markup/html code. Is this possible at all or must all code be created programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no designer support with Custom Controls.

See this support article to decide between two:

Overview of user controls vs. custom controls
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893667

Comment: Cheers Madhur. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: I am not aware of any technical reason. May be due to legacy reasons - when partial classes support was not present in C# and there could have been performance impact by separating code logic (.cs) with presentation(.ascx). That's just my guess.